# How do i make this console application

Tags: c#, console

I would like to know how can I writee a Console Application that gets the height and the side length of an equilateral triangle and presents its perimeter and area

```html
//Triangle Area = 1/2(base x height)
Console.Writeline("Please write the b value of the triangle:")`enter code here`
double bSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.write("Please write the h value of your triangle:")
double hSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double area = (bSide * hSide) / 2;
Console.Writeline("The area of your triangle is:", area);
```

Comment: [Perimeter](https://www.varsitytutors.com/high_school_math-help/how-to-find-the-perimeter-of-an-equilateral-triangle).

Answer (score 0):

You must watch out for character case when typing C# syntax, also watch out for missing semicolons. IDE and red squiggly line should warn you of those errors...

```
 //Triangle Area = 1/2(base x height)
        Console.WriteLine("Please write the b value of the triangle:");
        double bSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please write the h value of your triangle:");
        double hSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double area = (bSide * hSide) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("The area of your triangle is:" + Convert.ToString(area));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This guy's destined for a long and successful career writing mission critical software systems, if people keep doing his homework for him :)

Comment: but i have a question - why do i need the "Convert.ToString(area) i can just write + area and it will display the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
//Triangle Area = 1/2(base x height)
Console.Writeline("Please write the b value of the triangle:")`enter code here`
double bSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.write("Please write the h value of your triangle:")
double hSide = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double area = (bSide * hSide) / 2;
Console.Writeline("The area of your triangle is:{0}", area.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```